# item click custom listview basic4android

Tags: android, basic, basic4android

I made a customlistview in b4a but I can not fix the click event.

I want when button clicks image to pause and other buttons image to play
when click  image button is changed but other button image not change.

[image]

my code load

```
Sub load
For i = 0 To cur.RowCount-1
cur.Position=i
Dim p As Panel
play.Text = Chr(0xE037)
p.Initialize("p")
sco.Panel.AddView(p,1%x,top,98%x,500dip)
p.LoadLayout("layload")
play.Tag = cur.GetInt("id")
play.Typeface = awf
text.Text = cur.GetString("text")
top = top + 60dip + 2%x
Next
sco.Panel.Height = top + 10dip
End Sub
```

and code play

```
Sub play_Click
tim.Enabled = True
Dim lml As Label
lml.Initialize("lml")
lml = Sender
Dim curbv As Cursor
curbv = sql.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM tab1 ")
curbv.Position = lml.Tag - 1
sec = curbv.Position
meda.Load(File.DirAssets,curbv.GetString("mp"))
kl(lml)
End Sub
```

and my code for change icon

```
Sub kl( ln As Label) 
If ln.Text = Chr(0xE037) Then
ln.Text = Chr(0xE047)
meda.Play
load
Else If ln.Text = Chr(0xE047) Then
ln.Text = Chr(0xE037)
meda.Stop
End If
Sleep(100)
play.Text = Chr(0xE037)
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions, your English isn't expected to be perfect, but you can make your question a lot easier to read by using punctuation. At a minimum, use periods and question marks at the ends of sentences. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may show us some code, otherwise we can't tell you what you're doing wrong, and where to put the correction to your problem.